# Traefik Kubernetes 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect, kubernetes, traefik, http-redirect

I have traefik installed via the helm chart.

I have a domain: **example.com**

It has some blog posts.

I now created a subdomain: **subdomain.example.com**

I have the list of my blogs urls:

```
/blog-1
/blog-2
```

Both the base domain and the subdomain are on the same cluster.

I want to have 301 redirects so that if someone tries to visit:

```
example.com/blog-1
```

they would be redirected to:

```
subdomain.example.com/blog-1
```

I do not want to direct with a wildcard just with my list of blog urls.

Thanks

Here is my middleware for redirect to https

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-only
  namespace: exmaple
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
```

a  redirect is:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-redirectregex
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    regex: "https://example.com"
    replacement: "https://subdomain.example.com"
    permanent: true
```

can I have multiple redirectRegex in the same middleware?
I would then just have lots of them to redirect each url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one redirect per middleware, but you can have as many middleware as you want.

But in this case you can use the regex:

```
  redirectRegex:
    regex: "https://example.com/(blog-1|blog-2|whatever)"
    replacement: "https://subdomain.example.com/$1"
```

Comment: Oh nice, is there any limit to the length of the regex?

Comment: The syntax supported by Go's regexp library is documented at https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax.